# Import Multi-value Custom Data Fails for Household Contact Type

Tags: custom-fields, import, households

The "Import Multi-value Custom Data" fails when importing data into a multi-value custom field set that applies to only a Household contact type or Household sub-types. When the field set was change to "All Contacts" the import works. I didn't test it with multi-value custom field sets restricted to "Individual" or "Organization" contact types. It may fail with these also.

The Import Errors file show "Invalid value for field(s) : field ID; ; field ID; ; field ID; field ID" as the reason for the error when four fields are imported.

We use CiviCRM for WordPress.

To duplicate this setup a simple multi-value custom field set restricted to Households. Then try to import data into it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the relevant JIRA issue
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18959